# Notes. Mass Upload. Hitting some limit and getting "Note can't be saved"

Tags: data-loader, notes, data-import, contentnote

I'm doing data migration and need to upload ~500k Notes. 192k Notes were uploaded and now I'm getting `Note can't be saved` error via API and `Note contains characters that can't be saved` when trying to create any Note with any text via UI.

I think it some kind of daily limit because our storage limit is far from being reached but I can't find any documentation on this thing.

Did you do Notes migration and did you encounter similar issues? Or just have an idea of what can cause this?

Comment: Check out these two help articles from salesforce and if you have a more specific question we can try to resolve that. To me, this looks like a data formatting issue where some of the special characters are present in note body and that is not accepted by the database.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000340126&type=1&mode=1

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339316&type=1&mode=1

Comment: You can't insert Notes at all. Any Notes with any text, from UI too. Please read actual question text before writing comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard limit on inserting `ContentVersion`, which underlies Notes, is [200,000 per day](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334861&type=1&mode=1). I suspect you've reached that limit.

Unfortunately, I am not aware of a way to view the consumption of this limit within the org. It's not available in System Overview or via the Limits API. You may need to wait a day for it to roll over.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This article is hard to find)